# web.config transformations in section

Tags: c#, web.config-transform

I"m trying to setup web.config transformations. Is it possible to do with sections?

How would I transform all 3 values?

```
<section name="productinformationsettings" type="ProductInformation.Common.Configuration.ProductInformationConfigurationSection, ProductInformation.Common" />

<productinformationsettings ImageUrlBase="https://www.test.com" apikey="xxxxx" enivironment="test" />
```

When does Web.Debug.Config get used? When I'm debugging?

Comment: Configuration file transforms are applied at the time of build.

Comment: Transforms are applied during a publish, not a build.

Comment: Ok, and how can i use transforms to replace those 3 values?

Answer (score 0):

this is what i needed. xdt:Transform="Replace"